# ComponentArt Menu for touch devices

Tags: c#, android, .net, ipad, componentart

We have used component art TreeView 
**Currently this is how it works:**

- when we click on node it expands when we right click on desktop
  machine
- we get context menu with options

**now the problem is:**

- we need that context menu on touch devices.
- component art documentation website is down and support is also
  closed :(

```
<ComponentArt:Menu ID="GroupContextMenu" Orientation="Vertical" DefaultGroupCssClass="MenuGroup"
    DefaultItemLookId="DefaultItemLook" DefaultGroupItemSpacing="1" EnableViewState="false"
    ContextMenu="Custom" runat="server" ClientSideOnItemSelect="groupContextMenuClickHandlerS">
    <ItemLooks>
        <ComponentArt:ItemLook LookId="DefaultItemLook" CssClass="CAitem" HoverCssClass="CAitemHover"
            ExpandedCssClass="CAitemSelected" LeftIconWidth="16" LeftIconHeight="16" LabelPaddingLeft="2"
            LabelPaddingRight="8" LabelPaddingTop="3" LabelPaddingBottom="4" />
        <ComponentArt:ItemLook LookId="BreakItem" CssClass="MenuBreak" />
        <ComponentArt:ItemLook LookId="DisabledItemLook" CssClass="CAitemDisabled" />
    </ItemLooks>
</ComponentArt:Menu>
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: i have added code to my post